# Content-type is not JSON compatible while using Simple OAuth2 with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm looking to authenticate using [OAuth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2) with Azure AD.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/authorize", async (req, res) => {
  const credentials = {
    client: {
      id: "xxx",
      secret: "xxx"
    },
    auth: {
      tokenHost:
        "xxx"
    }
  };

  const oauth2 = require("simple-oauth2").create(credentials);
  const tokenConfig = {
    scope: "<scope>" 
  };

  const httpOptions = {};

  try {
    const result = await oauth2.clientCredentials.getToken(
      tokenConfig,
      httpOptions
    );
    const accessToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Access Token error", error.message);
  }
```

I followed the example provided by the repository but I'm getting an error `Access Token error The content-type is not JSON compatible`.

How can I authorize my OAuth2 with Microsoft Azure using NodeJS and Simple OAuth2?

Comment: Try taking this line out ```app.use(bodyParser.json());```

Comment: I have the same issue, but I am not using bodyParser.

Comment: IF you want to get Azure AD access token with node.js， you can use the sdk [msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-initializing-client-applications

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the error? I have the same issue..

Answer (score 4):

I came across this error also. The reason in my case was that the oAuth2 server was responding with a content-type header of text/plain - even though the body was actually JSON.

Changing the "json" configuration option to "force" in the http options of simple-oauth2 solved it for me.

Comment: Can you show me the actual code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing it to true `.getToken(tokenConfig, {json: true})`

Comment: In my case `client.getToken(tokenConfig, {json: 'force'})` worked. Using `json: true` would not return the json correctly.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are only using `tokenHost` you also need to add `tokenPath`.

Example:

```js
auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://example.com',
    tokenPath: '/path/to/token/endpoint/'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this: https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2/issues/279#issuecomment-569733862

Make sure that three urls are changed in the example. It works for me without `{json: true}`

This solution differs from the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/tutorials/node?tutorial-step=3)

Comment: The Github link mentions having a trailing slash on `tokenHost` and no leading slash on `tokenPath` and that was the solution for me. Surprisingly, the default `tokenPath` value has a leading slash, causing it to fail for me.

Answer (score 1):

set the auth property in this way

```
  auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/',
    tokenPath: 'oauth2/v2.0/token',
    authorizePath: 'oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
  },
```